# Reflection principle application

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I want to calculate the probability:

\begin{equation*}
P(W_4>2, \inf_{0\leq t\leq4} W_t >-1)
\end{equation*}

and $W$ is a Wiener process.

I tried:

\begin{equation*}
P(W_4>2, \inf_{0\leq t\leq4} W_t >-1)= P(W_4 >2)-P(W_4>2 \inf\ W_t <-1)
\end{equation*}

Then applying the reflection principle

\begin{equation*}
=P(W_4 >2)-P(W_4 <-3)= \phi(4/3)-\phi(1)
\end{equation*}

But my textbook says the solution should be:  $\phi(2)-\phi(1)$.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Could you elaborate how you applied the reflection principle?